# How do I find the master link on a Mongoose Intake dirt jump bike?

Tags: chain

[image]

I want to switch cranks on my Mongoose Intake dirt jump bike but can't find the master link

Comment: Relevant https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1726/how-can-i-tell-if-a-chain-has-a-master-link

Answer (score 5):

There is a good chance that there isn't a master link. Many single speeds do not have one on the factory installed  chain. It requires a chain tool to press out the pin. At that point a master link can be installed or a replacement pin can be installed using the chain tool. The chain does not need to be removed to change the crank unless it is worn. If you are changing crank or chain ring sizes you will need to either shorten your existing if it is serviceable or replacing it if its worn or too short.

Comment: Photo suggests its a 1-piece crank so the chainring will come off as well.

Comment: I have made an edit as some one piece crank assemblies do not have replaceable chain ring /cog.

Answer (score 5):

Master links on a single speed chain are fairly obvious, they have a clip in the outside of the chain link plate.

[image]

Your chain might not have a master link. It may have been joined by a link pin.

If you can get you wheel out of the frame, or at least push it forward in the dropouts enough you may be able to get the chain off the chainring, and there will be no need to break the chain.

Comment: Concur - Photo appears to show track ends, so moving wheel forward seems to be the first option to try.